# Materialize button collapse breakpoint

Tags: css, media-queries, materialize

My navbar contains too much buttons, so shortly before i reach the breakpoint which triggers the button collapse, the buttons overlap my brand logo, which looks ugly. How can i set the breakpoint of the `$('.button-collapse').sideNav();` so that it replaces the buttons at 1300px f.e instead of 600px?

edit: http://jsfiddle.net/kqjy7jbb/9/

Comment: Please upload a screenshot of your problem. Could you provide a jsfiddle for the same? It would help.

Comment: I added a fiddle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the container div in your code, that is causing the problems by condensing everything. It will fix the problem.

**HTML:** *(Nothing has been changed except removing the container div)*

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper blue-grey darken-4">
    <!-- <div class="container"> ONLY CHANGE-->
    <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse">
      <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
    </a>

    <a class="brand-logo light immersight-color" href="#"><b>Title</b></a>

    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li class="active test tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="100" data-tooltip="Grid Ansicht"><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">apps</i></a></li>
      <li class="test tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="100" data-tooltip="Panorama Ansicht">
        <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">view_quilt</i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="test tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="100" data-tooltip="Slide Ansicht">
        <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">view_carousel</i></a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn immersight-backgroundcolor">Login</a></li>
      <li><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn immersight-backgroundcolor">Registrieren</a></li>
      <li><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn immersight-backgroundcolor">Download Client</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- </div> -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS** *(optional, just added padding to Title brand logo)*:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 993px) {
  .brand-logo {
    margin-left: 15px;
    /* Margin for Title when all buttons are showed i.e. when screen size is large */
  }
}
```

**JQuery** *(nothing has been changed here either)*

```
$('.button-collapse').sideNav({
  menuWidth: '80%', // Default is 240
  edge: 'left', // Choose the horizontal origin
  closeOnClick: true // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0ez3xryp/1/)